# Removing Icon Bevel IN XCODE 4

Tags: iphone, icons, xcode4, bevelled

I know this shouldn't be ANY different than in a previous xcode and I know there are questions asking this BEFORE xcode 4 came out...

But the info.plist in xcode 4, instead of "Icon already includes gloss and bevel effects" it is "Icon already includes gloss effects", and I can't get rid of the bevel of the icon by choosing "NO".  Did they change it so that in xcode 4 you can NOT get rid of bevel effects?  Or am I just missing something?

My icons are the right size and PNG and everything... the icons work, i just can't get rid of bevel...

Is it just the iPhone Simulator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Icon already includes gloss effects` must be set to `YES`.

---

You have to click at the arrows (you can see them in my screenshot) and choose `YES` from drop-down menu.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ha ha ha . . . silly me... thankyou Kashiv . . . 
I guess the wording seemed a little confusing.  For further clarification, to any who see this question, it means: "Does your icon already have these effects so we don't need to add any?"  Ha ha.  Thankyou.

Comment: When I was migrating to Xcode4 I had the same problem with that :)
PS: Answer acception will be nicely welcomed :)

Comment: for some reason, after importing the project from Xcode 3 to 4, this variable changed from boolean to string. This is another thing to verify. Thanks.

Comment: I've got Xcode 4.2.1 and it does't seem to remove the gloss. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: @user826671: They moved the icon resources elsewhere in the Info.plist file; your best bet is to go to the project settings (by just choosing the project in the breadcrumb trail on top), scroll down to the Icon section and check Prerendered.